# simultaneous smallness

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, inequalities, sequences-and-series

> **QUESTION.** Given reals $0 < \epsilon, \delta < 1$, is it always possible to find $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$\begin{cases} \qquad \,\,\,\, \,(1-\delta^m)^n < \epsilon \\ 
> 1-(1-(\frac{\delta}2)^m)^n <\epsilon \,\,?
> \end{cases}$$

This might not be so hard but I wish to know.

Comment: Not at research level, I'm afraid.

Comment: One way is to solve n in terms of m, and show that if m is large enough then the interval always contains an integer.

Comment: Here's a way of looking at it: for large $m$, the expression $\frac{\log(1 - \delta^m)}{\log(1 - (\delta/2)^m)}$ is more or less on the order of $2^m$ by looking at Taylor series for the numerator and denominator, so for all sufficiently large $m$ we have $(1.5)^m < \frac{\log(1 - \delta^m)}{\log(1 - (\delta/2)^m)}$. Choose such $m$ so large that $\frac{\log(\epsilon/2)}{\log(1-\epsilon)} < (1.5)^m$, and take $n$ to be the ceiling of $\frac{\log(\epsilon/2)}{\log(1 - \delta^m)}$. Then we have $(1 - \delta^m)^n < \epsilon/2$ and $1 - \epsilon < (1 - (\delta/2)^m)^n$.

Comment: Putting @ToddTrimble's comment another way, the first line is approximately $e^{-n\delta^m}<\epsilon$, while the second line is approximately $e^{-n(\delta/2)^m}>1-\epsilon$. This can clearly be done simultaneously: first choose $m$ large enough so that the ratio between the two exponents is gigantic (you need to find an $a$ and an $m$ such that $e^a/e^{a/2^m}<\epsilon/(1-\epsilon)$). Then find an $n$ such that $n\delta^m=a$.